# Get two most frequent data from SQL tbl?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a tbl call it tbl_test in which continously data are inserting and it has approx 10^6 records at a time it has colums

Acquire_Id (Value between  1 to 20 ),

Status_Msg(value between 'A' to 'Z'),

Status_Code(value between 1 to 26)

There is one to one mapping b/w Status_Msg and Status_Code

Now i want to get two most frequent status_msg and Staus_Code Count for each acquirer if they are present in table

Query should be Cost Saving

Comment: (1) Edit your question with sample data and desired results.  (2) I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please add the appropriate tag for the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  You can get what you want using `row_number()` (or `rank()` or `dense_rank()`, depending on how ties are returned) after aggregating the values.

The following returns exactly two rows for each acquirer (even if there are ties).

```
select t.*
from (select t.acquire_id, t.status_msg, t.status_code, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.acquire_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from tbl_test t
      group by t.acquire_id, t.status_msg, t.status_code
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```